# Raspberry pi and ESP32

Tags: pi-3

i am working on a school project and i need help with it. i have MQTT client code that will run on the ESP32.It polls the DHT-22 and publishes the sensor data to a topic called temp humidity. then i have another script that ran on the raspberry pi 3 that will subscribe to the temp humidity topic and present the results to an OLED display. what i am thinking of doing is that i want to use another ESP32 that will connect to a LED strip which will subscribe to topic "temp humidity" and go over the data and when the temperature get higher than a certain number, for example 50c it should turn on the LED strip. "I need help making the code". i am using python for the main script on the raspberry pi 3 and micropython for the script on the ESP32.
Here is the MQTT client code that will run on the ESP32.

```
from time import sleep
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
from machine import Pin
from dht import DHT22

SERVER = '192.168.1.22'  # MQTT Server Address (Change to the IP address of your Pi)
CLIENT_ID = 'ESP32_DHT22_Sensor'
TOPIC = b'temp_humidity'

client = MQTTClient(CLIENT_ID, SERVER)
client.connect()   # Connect to MQTT broker

sensor = DHT22(Pin(15, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP))   # DHT-22 on GPIO 15 (input with internal pull-up resistor)

while True:
    try:
        sensor.measure()   # Poll sensor
        t = sensor.temperature()
        h = sensor.humidity()
        if isinstance(t, float) and isinstance(h, float):  # Confirm sensor results are numeric
            msg = (b'{0:3.1f},{1:3.1f}'.format(t, h))
            client.publish(TOPIC, msg)  # Publish sensor data to MQTT topic
            print(msg)
        else:
            print('Invalid sensor readings.')
    except OSError:
        print('Failed to read sensor.')
    sleep(4)
```

Here is the Raspberry Pi Python MQTT client code.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import Adafruit_SSD1306
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

disp = Adafruit_SSD1306.SSD1306_128_32(rst=0)
disp.begin()
FONT_PATH = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/piboto/PibotoCondensed-Regular.ttf'
FONT = ImageFont.truetype(FONT_PATH, 22)

def display_data(t, h):
    image = Image.new('1', (disp.width, disp.height))
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    # Draw temperature / Humidity values.
    draw.text((0, 8), '{0}°C'.format(t),  font=FONT, fill=255)
    draw.text((71, 8), '{0}%'.format(h), font=FONT, fill=255)
    # Draw bar charts.
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, 50, 8), outline=255, fill=0)
    draw.rectangle((71, 0, 121, 8), outline=255, fill=0)
    draw.rectangle((0, 0, t / 100.0 * 50, 8), outline=255, fill=255)
    draw.rectangle((71, 0, 71 + (h / 100.0 * 50), 8), outline=255, fill=255)
    # Send to OLED display.
    disp.clear()
    disp.image(image)
    disp.display()

    # Callback fires when conected to MQTT broker.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print('Connected with result code {0}'.format(rc))
    # Subscribe (or renew if reconnect).
    client.subscribe('temp_humidity')


# Callback fires when a published message is received.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    # Decode temperature and humidity values from binary message paylod.
    t,h = [float(x) for x in msg.payload.decode("utf-8").split(',')]
    print('{0}°C {1}%'.format(t, h))
    display_data(t, h)  # Display data on OLED display.


client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect  # Specify on_connect callback
client.on_message = on_message  # Specify on_message callback
client.connect('localhost', 1883, 60)  # Connect to MQTT broker (also running on Pi).

# Processes MQTT network traffic, callbacks and reconnections. (Blocking)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: What you are asking is possible as multiple devices can subscribe to the same topic.  What exactly is your question esp. if the Pi code is working...

Comment: You can try to make RPi to subscribe to temp/humidity topic and then publish to let's say 'led_state' topic when the temp is above some level. Your ESP connected to LED strip would have to subsribe to 'led_state' topic and react to commands sent by RPi. In this case your ESP code may be simplified.